# Multiple ggparcoord plots in one figure in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot three rows of plots into one big figure. I use the par() function in R to set this outline up, but then when I call the plotting function ggparcoord() three times, I instead get three separate plots:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=0.9)
ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=4:6, alphaLines=0.9)
ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=7:9, alphaLines=0.9)
```

First, How could I change my code to get the three ggparcoord plots onto one big figure? Second, Why does what I tried not work in this case?

EDIT:
It has been suggested to me to use grid.arrange. So, I tried this (and it works):

```
plot1 = ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=0.1)
plot2 = ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=0.2)
plot3 = ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=0.3)
plot4 = ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=0.4)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol=1)
```

I changed the plots slightly (kept columns all the same, and changed alphaLines) to better simulate the dataset I am working with, and this new problem that comes up with grid.arrange.

I am trying to write modifiable code such that I could change the number of plots (and a characteristic about them, such as alphaLines), possibly through a loop. For example, is it possible to use an index like i for this, and still be able to use grid.arrange with the output of each plot?:

```
for (i in 1:4){
  plot_i = ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=i/10)
  grid.arrange(plot_i, ..., ncol=1)
}
```

Comment: The `mfrow` is for base R plots. Have a look at `grid.arrange` in the `gridExtra` package

Comment: Thank you, @user20650! One thing I edited is that I would need to use this in a for loop, where I could change the number of plots to use. I updated/edited this part.

Comment: For something like this it is probably best to store the plots in a list. You can the arrange them after they have been generated... so move the `grid.arrange` outside the loop. This should give an idea: `plot_i  <- vector("list", length=4); for (i in 1:4)  {plot_i[[i]] = ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=i/10)} ; do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_i, ncol=2))`

Comment: You also may find it easier  in this case to use  `lapply` (no need to specify the output vector): `lst <- lapply(1:4, function(i) ggparcoord(mtcars, columns=1:3, alphaLines=i/10));
do.call("grid.arrange", c(lst, ncol=2))`